# wget - Download a sub directory

Tags: wget

How do I download only a sub directory using wget?
Can I specify the subdirectory that I need to download?

Thanks!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can do:

`wget -r -l1 --no-parent http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/`

where:

```
-r: recursive retrieving
-l1: sets the maximum recursion depth to be 1
--no-parent: does not ascend to the parent; only downloads from the specified subdirectory and downwards hierarchy
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking down the command arguments. I had a similar problem but only needed the -r and --no-parent commands.

Comment: If you would like to ensure each page can be loaded correctly (ie: download images loaded on the pages), you can add the **-p** flag to the above command.

Comment: Also, add `-nd` to save the files directly in your current directory without the /path/to/the/subdirectory.

Comment: -nH --cut-dirs <num of previous dirs> to not download the entire path tree.

Answer (score 20):

```
$ wget -m -p -E -k -K -np {URL Address}
```

You can use the man page for details of options.

**NOTE:** with the previous options, index of files will be download!

- -m: options suitable for mirroring such as infinite recursion and timestamps
- -p: page-requisites
- -E: adjust extension
- -k: convert links for local viewing
- -K: backup original, don't clobber
- -np: No parent

Comment: Insane. Right what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This solution fails in my case (GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on linux-gnu).  It actually downloads files in parent directories --- not the desired result.

Comment: In my case it also fails. It seems that my `wget` (GNU Wget 1.14) ignores `--no-parent option`. In openSUSE leap 42.1.20160217

Comment: **-m**: options suitable for mirroring such as infinite recursion and timestamps

**-p** : page-requisites
**-E** : adjust extension
**-k** : convert links for local viewing
**-K**: backup original, don't clobber
**-np** : No parent

Answer (score 4):

Good information I was able to use. I tried:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/
```

on a site that included multiple files of the form name.subname.subname2.etc.htm or .html. In order to pick these up I ran:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/
```

and this worked fine.