# Where to download documentation for Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Where can I download documentation for Spark? Although its available as [web-pages](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html), it will be much easier to have it attached to source in Eclipse.

**I know it is not a strictly programming question, but I cannot think of any other place to ask this question.**

Comment: I didn't downvote but: 1. The docs you're looking for are in the [Spark repo](https://github.com/apache/spark). 2. You can ask questions like this on the [Spark user list](http://spark.apache.org/community.html).

Comment: I think it's perfectly on-topic. The documentation is part of Spark and used for programming. It's a directly answerable question too. I have no idea about the answer though. What format do you need for use in Eclipse?

Comment: Nick and Daniel: Thanks guys! Nick: I tried what you said and generated HTML files, but the Eclipse is still not able to show the documentation. @DanielDarabos: I think HTML is the format which works with Eclipse. Not 100% sure though, never done this before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **wget** to download the spark latest document.

```
mkdir spark_latest_docs
cd spark_latest_docs
wget -m -p -E -k -K -np https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/
open ./spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21875199/3907204

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found this page while searching for the answer. Below is what worked for me.
Note: you need to have Ruby and Python installed. See instuctions in this [Readme](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/README.md)
under 'Prerequisites'

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git
```

Optionally, change branches if you want documentation for a specific version of Spark
e.g. I wanted Scala docs for Spark 1.6

```
git branch -a
git checkout remotes/origin/branch-1.6
```

cd into the docs directory

```
cd docs
```

Run jekyll build - see the Readme above for options

```
jekyll build
```

Optinonally move the API docs somewhere else

```
mv <path/to/spark>/docs/api <other/location/
```

Note: The pre-built Spark tarball doesn't seem to include the docs directory for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WinHTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/) or any other offline website download engine.