# wget download a section of a website

Tags: wget

I want to download a particular section of a website. I am following this [wget - Download a sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507198/wget-download-a-sub-directory) . But the problem is the section of the website does not have any particular url i.e. the urls goes like this `http://grephysics.net/ans/0177/*` where * is a number from 1-100 and I cant use `http://grephysics.net/ans/0177` in wget. How do I download this 100 webpages with link to each other (i.e. the the Previous and Next button should link to local copies)

Comment: Let's back up a minute. I guess I assumed you were using bash or something similar on linux. What shell are you using to run your `wget`?

Comment: do you still need this question answered? What shell are you using to run `wget`?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need:

`wget -p -k  http://grephysics.net/ans/0177/{1..100}`

**Explanation:**

`-k` : rewrites links to point to local assets

`-p` : get all images, js, css, etc. needed to display the page

`{1..100}` : this specifies a range of urls to download, in your case we have pages labelled 1 to 100.

**Why didn't recursive downloading work?**

The link you posted was a good first resource, probably what most people would want. But the way wget recursively downloads is by getting the first page specified (i.e. the root), then **following links** to child pages. The way grephysics is set up however, is that http://grephysics.net/ans/0177 leads us to a 404. **It has no links** for wget to follow to download child pages.

---

**If your wget doesn't support** `{}`

You can still have the same results by using the following command:

`for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done | wget -p -k -B http://grephysics.net/ans/0177/ -i -`

**Explanation**

`for i in {1..100};...` : This prints the values 1 to 100.

`|` : For anyone who hasn't seen this, we are piping the output of the previous command into the input of the following command

`-p` : get all images, js, css, etc. needed to display the page

`-k` : rewrite the links to point to the local copies

`-B` : specifies the base URL to use with the `-i` option

`-i` : reads a list of urls to fetch from a file. Since we specified the 'file' `-` it reads from stdin.

So, we read in the values 1 to 100 and append them to our base url 
`http://grephysics.net/ans/0177/` and fetch all of those urls and all the assets that go with them, then rewrite links so we can browse offline.

Comment: Have you tried running this, this isn't working for me.

Comment: `wget -p -k  http://grephysics.net/ans/0177/{1..100}

--2017-11-11 18:41:13--  http://grephysics.net/ans/0177/%7B1..100%7D

Resolving grephysics.net (grephysics.net)... 64.150.181.80

Connecting to grephysics.net (grephysics.net)|64.150.181.80|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-11-11 18:41:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.`

Comment: Hmm... it looks like your version of wget doesn't understand specifying a range. I'll do some more looking.

Comment: output : i was unexpected at this time.